# How to re-executing the code in another ViewController after pressing a button

Tags: ios

I have a ViewController called VC,and another called ContainerVC. I want the game to act like this: when a certain condition is satisfied in VC, the ContainerVC will pop out, and if I press a button, it will reset the game.

I am a noob in cocoa programming so...my question may sound dumb, but many thanks if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

This is the best place to start.  Not only does it contain the answers to your questions, but it will also tell you fundamentals which you must learn in order to develop basic apps.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1